# Loop synchronous multiple async.whilst

Tags: node.js, loops, async.js

I want to use many included loops in node.js in *synchronous* mode.

Example :

```
for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < length3; k++) {
      //completed 3
    }
    //completed 2
  }
  //do completed 1
}
```

How to do this with async? I tried this :

```
exports.myFunction = function (callback) {
  var finalListA = new Array();
  var pos = 0;
  Model_A.find().populate('listOfItems')
    .lean().exec(function (err, As) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err, null);
      } else {
        //For each A
        var i = 0;
        async.whilst(
          function () {
            return i < As.length;
          },
          function (callback1) {
            var isActive = false;
            //For each B into the A
            var j = 0;
            async.whilst(
              function () {
                return j < As[i].Bs.length;
              },
              function (callback2) {
                Model_B.findById(AS[i].Bs[j]._id, function (err, B) {
                  if (err) {} else {
                    var k = 0;
                    // For each C in the B
                    async.whilst(
                      function () {
                        return k < B.Cs.length;
                      },
                      function (callback3) {
                        if (B.Cs[k].dateEnd >= Date.now()) {
                          isActive = true;
                        }
                        k++;
                        callback3();
                      },
                      function (err) {
                        console.log("3 COMPLETED");
                      }
                    );
                  }
                });
                j++;
                callback2();
              },
              function (err) {
                console.log("2 COMPLETED");
                if (err) {} else {
                  if (isActive == true) {
                    finalListA[pos] = As[i];
                    pos = pos + 1;
                  }
                }
              }
            );
            i++;
            callback1();
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log("1 COMPLETED");
            if (err) {} else {
              return callback(null, finalListA);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
}
```

The trace shows me :

- COMPLETED 2
- COMPLETED 2
- COMPLETED 1
- COMPLETED 3
- COMPLETED 3

The order expected is :

- COMPLETED 3
- COMPLETED 3
- COMPLETED 2
- COMPLETED 2
- COMPLETED 1

Comment: Have you had a look at Child Process http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: No, I don't understand the interest of child process for my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the callbacks of the higher loops from the end callback of your `whilst` loop (like you did with the outermost `callback`), instead of calling them synchronously from the `whilst` body in which you just *started* the next level iteration.

Btw, I don't know what you actually want to do, but [`whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async/#whilst) does not seem the best choice for iterating arrays. Use the parallel [`each`](https://github.com/caolan/async/#each) or the serial [`eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async/#eachSeries) (or their `map` or `reduce` equivalents).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently created simpler abstraction called **wait.for** to call async functions in sync mode (based on Fibers). It's at an early stage but works. It is at:

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Using **wait.for**, you can call any standard nodejs async function, as if it were a sync function.

I do not understand exactly what are you trying to do in your code. Maybe you can explain your code a little more, or give some data example.
I dont' know what Model_A or Model_B are... I'm guessing most of your code, but...

using **wait.for** your code migth be:

```
var wait=require('wait.for');

exports.myFunction = function(callback) {
  //launchs a Fiber
  wait.launchFiber(inAFiber,callback);
}

function inAFiber(callback) {
    var finalListA = new Array();
    var pos = 0;

    var x= Model_A.find().populate('listOfItems').lean();
    As = wait.forMethod(x,"exec");
    //For each A
    for(var i=0;i<As.length;i++){
        var isActive = false;
        //For each B into the A
        for(var j=0; j < As[i].Bs.length;j++){
           var B=wait.forMethod(Model_B,"findById",AS[i].Bs[j]._id);
           // For each C in the B
           for(var k=0; k < B.Cs.length;k++){
              if(B.Cs[k].dateEnd >= Date.now()) {
                  isActive = true;
              }
            }
            console.log("3 COMPLETED");
        }
        console.log("2 COMPLETED");
        if(isActive == true) {
            finalListA[pos] = As[i];
            pos = pos + 1;
        }
    };
    console.log("1 COMPLETED");
    return callback(null,finalListA);
}
```

Also, for what I see, you should break the loops as soon as you find one item (isActive), and you don't need the var pos. Doing that your code will be:

```
var wait=require('wait.for');

exports.myFunction = function(callback) {
  //launchs a Fiber
  wait.launchFiber(inAFiber,callback);
}

function inAFiber(callback) {
    var finalListA = [];

    var x= Model_A.find().populate('listOfItems').lean();
    As = wait.forMethod(x,"exec");
    var isActive;
    //For each A
    for(var i=0;i<As.length;i++){
        isActive = false;
        //For each B into the A
        for(var j=0; j < As[i].Bs.length;j++){
           var B=wait.forMethod(Model_B,"findById",AS[i].Bs[j]._id);
           // For each C in the B
           for(var k=0; k < B.Cs.length;k++){
              if(B.Cs[k].dateEnd >= Date.now()) {
                  isActive = true;
                  break;//for each C
              }
            } //loop for each C

            console.log("3 COMPLETED");
            if (isActive) break;//for each B

        } //loop for each B
        if (isActive) finalListA.push(As[i]);
        console.log("2 COMPLETED");
    } //loop for each A
    console.log("1 COMPLETED");
    return callback(null,finalListA);
}
```